# Java JList not appearing

Tags: java, applet, jlist

On every JList I've made... I've had to CLICK on it before ANY of the JList would show up. It was like... invisible but still there... UNTIL I clicked on it...

I have tried `list.setVisible(true)` and such... but no luck.  :\ Help? Yes, I tried the Javadoc, Google, AND SO Search. >_< I have never encountered a problem like this.

Code:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JList;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class inventory extends JApplet implements MouseListener {

public static String newline;
public static JList list;
int gold = 123;

    public void init() {



ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
arr.add("Hatchet");
arr.add("Sword");
arr.add("Shield");
arr.add(gold + " Gold");
System.out.println("You have " + arr.size() + " items in your inventory.");
showInventory(arr);



        list = new JList(arr.toArray());

        add(list);

        list.addMouseListener(this);

        list.setVisible(true);

    }

public static void showInventory (ArrayList<String> theList) {
for (int i = 0; i < theList.size(); i++) {
System.out.println(theList.get(i));
}
}


    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        Object index = list.getSelectedValue();
       System.out.println("You have selected: " + index);
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) { }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) { }




    public void paint(Graphics g) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or if you want to override the paint method, replace it with:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
   super.paint(g);
   // your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to erase this part from your code:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {

}
```

Basicly your problem was that you were overwriting the paint method with an empty method. That is why your list was not displaying properly at start.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `this.setVisible(true);` line at the end of the `init()` method like

```
list.addMouseListener(this);

list.setVisible(true);
this.setVisible(true);
```